# MongoDb Query $or $and

Tags: mongodb

I have these types of documents in a collection:

```
{"action": "add", "text": "a"},
{"action": "remove", "text": "a"},
{"action": "add", "text": "a"},
{"action": "add", "text": "b"},
{"action": "remove", "text": "b"},
{"action": "add", "text": "c"},
```

Now I want to get all entries where all of these conditions exist:

- `text` matches my param, e.g. `a`
- Only get the entries where the number of `action` equals `add` entries is greater by one then the number of `action` equals `remove` entries

Given see sample data above the query for `action` `a` or `c` should yield a result while `b` should yield no results.

Needs to be supported by MongoDb 3.4.

Comment: Are these elements documents, or part of documents?

Comment: They're all documents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Veeram solution, you can group on text field(no need of match operation) so that you can get the response as per expected.

> Given see sample data above the query for action a or c should yield a result while b should yield no results.

```
 db.collection.aggregate([ 
  {"$group":{
    "_id":"$text",
   "action_add":{"$sum":{"$cond":[{"$eq":["$action","add"]},1,0]}},
   "action_remove":{"$sum":{"$cond":[{"$eq":["$action","remove"]},1,0]}},
   "data":{"$push":"$$ROOT"}
  }},
  {"$addFields":{"diff":{"$subtract":["$action_add","$action_remove"]}}},
  {"$match":{"diff":1}},
  {"$unwind":"$data"},
  {"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":"$data"}}
])
```